# Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable while assigning value to @ObservedObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
struct ParentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var selectedFruit:Fruit
  @State var showingSheet = false

  var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing:0.6) {
                ForEach(self.viewModel.fruits, id: \.id) { record in
                    Text(record).onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedFruit = Fruit() //Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
                        self.showingSheet.toggle()
                    }
                }
             }

        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet,onDismiss: {
                print("reload?")
        }) { 
             DetailView(fruit: self.selectedFruit)
        }
   }
}  




struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fruit: Fruit
    var body: some View {
        Text(fruit.text)
    }
}
```

When I try to assign value to the observable `selectedFruit` from `ParentView`, I get the following compile error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable

But if I replace `@ObservedObject` with `@State`, it works. How can I make it work with `@ObservedObject`? I'm worried, if I go with @State, the update I make on that object on `DetailView` will not trigger update on `ParentView`.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you could mutate `self`, you don't want to do this.

An `@ObservedObject` is a reference to an object instance that is injected into your view, typically from a superview, or if `ParentView` is your root view, from your scene delegate.

By assigning a new value to `selectedFruit` you would be changing the object referred to in **this view**. but the parent view would still refer to the original object.

Your `selectedFruit` should be an `@Published` property of your `viewModel`.  You would then have `self.viewModel.selectedFruit = record` in your `onTapGesture`.

This Paul Hudson [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject) provides a good overview of the difference between an observable object, a state property and the environment.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was missing. It should be an `@Published` property with a  ViewModel as an `@ObservableObject`.
Thanks for your help!